# Django - render only partial / change context / change form after POST without refresh

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I need some help with django

I have kind of landing page with form, which need to have 3 different states. 
Flow looks like this: enter email -> check database for user with that email -> render login or register form, still in same template.

Code looks like this:

.html

```
// lots of code 

<form method="POST" id="form">
{{ form.as_p }}
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>

// lots of code
```

and in views.py i have render method with context

```
return render(
            request,
            'apply.html',
            context,
        )
```

where in context i placed simple standard django form like:

```
class ApplyForm(forms.Form):
  email = forms.CharField()
  phone = forms.CharField()
```

Is there and way to change ApplyForm to LoginForm or RegisterForm after sending POST from first one, without refreshing whole page?

I though about injecting all three forms to context, sending some ajax request, and then differentiate which form should be displayed, but I'm not sure how could it be done...

thanks in advance!

Comment: You will have to do AJAX. However, this question is too broad. If you have a specific problem let us know. Otherwise, here's a tutorial to get you started: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: Is it like the page has an input field for email, and you want to check if the email exists or not if it does then render the login form else the signup form? If yes then have you tried AJAX?